# How swift creates instance with init()?

Tags: swift

This is question for curiosity, How does init() function create instance?

- Why when we assign values in init method makes instance? and How?
- I feel like init() is just a method with assigning values without any return types but how!!! does it make return instance when we call it?
  Anyone knows the answer? I read init() document but still not getting it. Anyone knows the answer?
  Thank you for reading!

```swift
struct Rect {
    var origin = Point()
    var size = Size()
    init() {}
}

let basicRect = Rect()
```

How is this working????????

Comment: I think the simplest answer is what is on the Swift doc's page: "Initialization is the process of preparing an instance of a class, structure, or enumeration for use. This process involves setting an initial value for each stored property on that instance and performing any other setup or initialization that’s required before the new instance is ready for use." https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html

Comment: In other words, init != constructor. In my understanding, it's like a setter method to set the object's uninitialized variables.

Answer (score 0):

**The initializer is used in stored property:**

1. Initializer is used in stored property to create an initial value.
2. Initializer is used in stored property to assign default property value within the property definition.

**In Swift, init() is used to an initialize an instance.**